# Sub-dimensional subspaces a null set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

> Let $m<n$ and $f: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be continuously differentiable. Show $$\lambda^n(f(\mathbb{R}^m))=0$$ and conclude from this, that every linear subspace $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\dim E < n$ is a null set as well.

The result seems rather obvious, yet I'm not able to prove it.

About the second part: If $m:=\dim E<n$, $E$ it's clearly isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$. But is there some canonical isomorphism that satisfies $f(\mathbb{R}^m)=E$ and is continuously differentiable?

I tried to apply some isomorphism-argument for the first part, too, but didn't find it very helpful because of the generality of $f$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can apply Sard's lemma, since $m<n$ and $f$ is $C^1$ we see that $\operatorname{rk} Df(x) < n$ for all $x$. Hence $f(\mathbb{R}^m)$ has measure zero.

If $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a subspace with dimension $m<n$, then let $b_1,...,b_m$ be a basis and define $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by $f(x) = \sum_k x_k b_k$. $f$ is smooth, hence from the above we have $f(\mathbb{R}^m) = E$ has measure zero.

Comment: Seems good. However, we've only introduced a reduced version of Sard's Lemma that gives your statement, but only for $C^1$-functions that are defined on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ in this case. We can isomorphically identify $\mathbb{R}^m$ with a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, but that subset will in general not be open? So I'm thinking of some additional argument that is required here.

Comment: No, its simpler than that. Define $\phi:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by $\phi(x) = f((x_1,...,x_m))$. Then $\phi$ is $C^1$, $\operatorname{rk} D \phi(x) \le m < n$ for all $x$, and hence $\phi(\mathbb{R}^n) = f(\mathbb{R}^m)$ has measure zero.

Comment: So simpel, so beautiful. I like that! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb R^m$ is a countable union of cubes, it is enough to show that $\lambda^n(f(Q))=0$ for any closed cube $Q\subset \mathbb R^m$.

Translating and dilating, we may assume that $Q$ is the unit cube $[0,1]^m$. For any $K\in\mathbb N$, the cube $Q$ can be decomposed into $K^m$ cubes $Q_i$ of size $\frac1K\cdot$ Now, $f$ is $\mathcal C^1$ and hence Lipschitz on $Q$; so each $f(Q_i)$ is contained in a cube of size $\leq C\times\frac1K$, for some absolute constant $C$. Hence, $f(Q)$ is contained in the union of $K^m$ cubes of size $\leq C\times\frac1K$, so that 
$$\lambda^n(f(Q))\leq K^m\times \left(\frac{C}K\right)^n:=\frac{C'}{K^{n-m}}\, .$$
Since $K\in\mathbb N$ is arbitrary, this shows that $\lambda^n(f(Q))=0$.

For the second part, just choose (as you did) any linear isomorphism $f:\mathbb R^m\to E$, which is of course $\mathcal C^1$ (being linear) when considered as a map from $\mathbb R^m$ into $\mathbb R^n$.